# Struggling with the difference between O, Ω, and Θ?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am currently taking a paper about data structures and algorithms. I have a final exam approaching and I know there will be questions regarding the worst-case time complexity for various sorting and searching algorithms.

I think I understand the general idea of O, Ω, and Θ. O denotes the upper bound, Ω denotes the upper and lower bound and Θ denotes the lower bound.

So if we consider question (b) from the example below, I am confused as to whether my answer should be O(n log n) or Θ(n log n)?

Initially I had thought Θ was exclusively for worst-case time complexity, but I see people refer to worst-case time complexity with O aswell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay you have some backwards,
so big O notation denotes the worst case, and is an upperbound.

Big Theta  denotes a tight asymptotic bound. This means the worst and best case fall along the same function. Essentially, we use Big Theta when Big O and Big Omega  give us the same bounds.

Big Omega denotes the best case, a lower bound.

In general use Big O for the worst case, and use big theta when the worst and best case are the same. If you only use Big O and Big Omega you will be entirely objectively correct